# Append similar strings in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the below code where I need to replace or append strings which is of same names. How can this be done ?

I need to append or replace the column "ATTRIBUTENAME" values with integer based on IDNUM .

```
         CREATE TABLE #STATICFILTER
         (
       IDNUM INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1),
       ATTRIBUTENAME VARCHAR(MAX),
            )

       Insert into #STATICFILTER
       Select * from SPLIT((Select ERSBusinessLogic_Inputs from            


       ERSBusinessLogic WHERE ERSBusinessLogic_ID =@BusinessID ))

      CREATE TABLE #STATICFILTER2
       (
         IDNUM INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1),
         ATTRIBUTENAME VARCHAR(MAX),
         STATICID INTEGER
          )
        Insert into #STATICFILTER2
        Select M.ATTRIBUTENAME,SL.ERSStatisticType_ID from #STATICFILTER M                    
        LEFT join [CoSD].[ERSStatisticType_LU] SL
        ON M.ATTRIBUTENAME collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS  =  
        SL.ERSStatisticType_Attribute collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 

       UPDATE #STATICFILTER2
       SET ATTRIBUTENAME = ATTRIBUTENAME + CAST(RN AS varchar(1)) FROM 
                (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ATTRIBUTENAME ORDER  
                                                            BY IDNUM) AS RN
                 FROM #STATICFILTER2) AS NEWATTRIBUTENAME
```

Incluidng some results as per the below comments....

```
                  #STATICFILTER2 has the below values

                   IDNUM    Attributename  Inputvalues
                   ------------------------------------
                      1         IMPORTS      45
                      2         IMPORTS      23
                      3         IMPORTS      28
```

when i execute the above update code the values are getting updated as

```
                   IDNUM    Attributename  Inputvalues
                   ------------------------------------
                      1         IMPORTS1      45
                      2         IMPORTS1      23
                      3         IMPORTS1      28
```

Instead of getting updated as

```
                   IDNUM    Attributename  Inputvalues
                   ------------------------------------
                      1         IMPORTS1      45
                      2         IMPORTS2      23
                      3         IMPORTS3      28
```

Comment: It would help if you showed some sample data along with the expected result.

Comment: Hi.. included the comments as per your suggestion... let me know if you need any furhter details..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with SQL Server's UPDATE FROM, so I cannot tell what's wrong with your update statement. But you can solve it by using a WITH clause instead of FROM:

```
with upd as
(
  select s.*, row_number() over (partition by attributename order by idnum) as rn
  from #staticfilter s
)
update upd
set attributename = attributename + cast(rn as varchar);
```

I think the difference is that here with WITH you create a view containing row numbers and you update the underlying table, whereas with FROM you update the table and look up values with FROM, so for every row FROM is being evaluated and results in row number 1, because it's just one row you are looking at at a time. But this may be wrong; as mentioned, I am not familiar with this syntax.